# some error disturbs me

Tags: android, android-studio

When we  want  to  run an  Android Project it gives me an  error. Tthe error  is java: 
编码UTF-8的不可映射字符 , I don't  know  how  to  solve  it,also  we  want to  say  the Project  was programmer by someone else.

Comment: Please post stack trace of the error. Not only does that error not make grammatical sense but it seems to suggest you are trying to encode/decode a character in UTF-8 when that character doesn't have a mapping. Corrupt data stream perhaps? We can't give you answers if there isn't any code.

Comment: I  m  sorry,i  m  a  newer  here,the  code  in package com.gp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //����ȫ��
  this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  //��ʾ�Զ����SurfaceView��ͼ
  setContentView(new MySurfaceView(this));
 }
}

Comment: Add what you just typed into the question with proper formatting. So that its immediately obvious to others too...

Comment: My Chinese is a little rusty but I think your source may contain invalid characters. Try saving the source files with UTF-8 encoding before compiling.

Comment: yes,you are  right,do you have solution for  this  problem ,this  project  was  in  android studio.i  have  search  for  long  time,but  it  didn't give  me a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you use Chinese characters within your code, which cannot be resolved by the compiler. Add the above lines to `build.gradle` in your project solves the error.

```
tasks.withType(Compile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

Comment: I,m  sorry,your  answer I  have  tried,but  it  didn't work,thank  for  help